# Reference documents with ObjectId when saving in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have the following schemas:

```
// ingredient
var ingredSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  cost: Number
});

// order
var orderSchema = new Schema({
  cusName: String,
  ingredients: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Ingredient'}]
});

// create model
var Ingredient = mongoose.model('Ingredient', ingredSchema);
var Order = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema);
```

I have already saved a bunch ingredients in a collection `ingredients` and have a UI where users choose a set of ingredients for their burgers. I then try to save an order for a burger in another collection `orders` within the same database `burgers` like this:

```
// get order info from the form
var newOrder = new Order({ cusName: req.body.name, 
                           ingredients: req.body.ingredients });
newOrder.save(function(err) {
    if (err)
        return console.log('Could not save your new order', err);
    res.redirect('/order');
});
```

The call to save an order generates the following error:

```
{ message: Cast to ObjectId failed for value xxx at path 'ingredients',
  name: 'CastError',
  type: ObjectId,
  value: xxx,
  path: 'ingredients' }
```

I use mongoose version 3.6.11. Please help me hack this.

PS: req.body.ingredients is an array built from checkboxes.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are 2 possible problems with your code right now:

**1. `req.body.ingredients` will not be an array of `ObjectId`s, and mongoose wants it alright (I doubt of this one).**

You should cast every ingredient to `ObjectId` first. Supposing `req.body.ingredients` is array, then you would do something like this:

```
var casted = req.body.ingredients.map(function( ingredient ) {
  return mongoose.Types.ObjectId(ingredient);
});
```

I did not tested this, see if it'll work for you.

**2. Mongoose is trying to cast your ingredients, but one of them is not a valid `ObjectId`**

`ObjectId` should be composed of 24 hex chars, check whether you're passing values like this to Mongoose.

---

Please, post the result if one of them work for you :)

Comment: I ran option 1 and express throws an error: `Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters`. I am still trying to wrap my head around this `ObjectId` thing.

Comment: Well, check option 2 now. You may not be passing valid `ObjectId`s.

Comment: You got it! Option two nails it. The problem was that I had `ingred.name` populated in the `req.body.ingredients` instead of `ingred._id`. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Weird thing for me is when I look in the database, the ObjectID's are different than the ones I feed the program. For example I want it save a reference to ingredient `123` (i.e. `ObjectId(123)`) but in the database I see it as a totally different number